# There are 4 identical oak trees, 2 identical maple trees and 3 identical pine trees. How many arrangements start with maples?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I've  been self studying probability and I'm confused.
How do you put maples in the first position and then calculate the arrangements?

Comment: Do you want the first tree to be maple? Or the first 2 trees to be maple trees?

Comment: First tree to be maple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have in total $9$ trees, but if the first one is a maple tree then you still have $8$ trees to place in any way you want, and that will be $8!$ ways.

Also because the oak and pine trees are identical so you divide by $4!×3!$ (because it doesn't differ if the oak number $1$ is before oak number $2$ or oak number $2$ is before oak number $1$ since they are identical)

The total answer of ways will be $\frac{8!}{3!×4!}=280$

Comment: Why not also divide by 2! For the maples?

Comment: We are actually dividing by $1!$ for the maple tree, because we fixed a maple tree in the begining (one of the 2 maples without precising which one is it) and now we are just arranging the $8$ trees left.

Answer (score 2):

We can only choose the order of second to ninth trees. So we need to sort 4 oak trees, 1 maple tree and 3 pine trees. There are $\frac{8!}{3!1!4!}=280$ ways of ordering the trees.

Answer (score 2):

Place a maple tree as first.

Then $4$ identical oak trees, $1$ maple tree and $3$ identical pine tree must follow.

Taking into account that the trees of one sort are identical there are $$\frac{8!}{4!1!3!}$$possibilities for that.